# How long does the effect of the Wild Hunt aura last?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, conditions

The [Wild Hunt Archer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=2214) (and all Wild Hunt enemies) has the ability "Wild Gaze" which is an Aura ability that reads:

> Those who meet the gaze of a wild hunt archer come face-to-face with the hunt's fearful power and find it difficult to act in the face of such a legendary legacy. When a creature ends its turn in the aura, it must succeed at a DC 34 Will save to resist becoming slowed 1 (slowed 2 on a critical failure). The wild hunt archer can deactivate or activate this aura by using a single action, which has the concentrate trait.

How long does the "Slowed" status inflicted by this ability last? Normally, Slowed always has a duration given, and the status itself does not say anything about when it ends.

Comment: Only kind of. I might need to reword my question a bit, mostly what I am wondering about is If the bestiary entry has an error in it and the duration is just missing.

Comment: Though I assume the answer for that is "No way to know, but probably." So yeah, thinking about it, the answers to that question answer this one, kind of. Close enough anyway.